# Is PID = 0 a valid for usb device?

Tags: usb, driver, device, pid, wdk

I'm going to create device with Product Id `(PID) = 0x0000`, create driver for this device and sign it using Microsoft Windows Driver Kit (WDK). Is 0x0000 a valid PID for `USB` device in Windows?

`PID=0x0000` will be a generic `PID` for all my devices (for development purposes), because I already have `PID=0x0001, PID=0x0002` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  As far as I know, there is nothing in the USB specification that prevents the product ID from being 0, so you should be fine.  This [listing of USB IDs](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) contains several instances of USB devices with a product ID of 0.

Keep in mind that your product still must have a valid vendor ID, which you are supposed to get assigned to you by the [USB Implementers Forum](http://usb.org).

Comment: Note that a USB VID currently costs [US$5000](http://www.usb.org/developers/vendor/).  Some silicon vendors USB controllers or MCUs with USB to sell may sell you a range of PIDs under their own VID.